# What do "//sys ..." comments mean?

Tags: go

Microsoft's winio package contains comments starting with //sys.
For example:

```
//sys connectNamedPipe(pipe syscall.Handle, o *syscall.Overlapped) (err error) = ConnectNamedPipe
```

I suspect they have special meaning.
What do these comments mean?
And where is the documentation?

Comment: I suspect [this](https://go.dev/src/cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/README) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

[mkwinsyscall](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Microsoft/go-winio/tools/mkwinsyscall) uses the `//sys` comments to determine what code it needs to generate:

> mkwinsyscall generates windows system call bodies. It parses all files specified on command line containing function prototypes (like syscall_windows.go) and prints system call bodies to standard output.
> The prototypes are marked by lines beginning with "//sys" and read
> like func declarations if //sys is replaced by func, but...

Running [`go generate`](https://go.dev/blog/generate) will lead to it being called due to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/go-winio/blob/main/syscall.go#L5) (with output going to [zsyscall_windows.go](https://github.com/microsoft/go-winio/blob/main/zsyscall_windows.go)):

```
//go:generate go run github.com/Microsoft/go-winio/tools/mkwinsyscall -output zsyscall_windows.go ./*.go
```